# identifying number of words in a paragraph using haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and functional programing. I have a `.txt` file which contains some paragraphs. I want to count the number of words in each paragraph, using Haskell.

I have written the input/output code

```
paragraph-words:: String -> int


no_of_words::IO()
no_of_words=
do
    putStrLn "enter the .txt file name:"
    fileName1<- getLine
    text<- readFile fileName1
            let wordscount= paragraph-words text
```

Can anyone help me to write the function paragraph-words. which will calculate the number of words in each paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of lines can be split into paragraphs if one takes all lines until at least one empty line (`""`) is reached or the list is exhausted (1). We ignore all consecutive empty lines (2) and apply the same method for the rest of our lines:

```
type Line      = String
type Paragraph = [String]

parify :: [Line] -> [Paragraph]
parify [] = []
parify ls 
  | null first = parify rest          
  | otherwise  = first : parify rest
  where first = takeWhile (/= "") ls  -- (1) take until newline or end
        rest  = dropWhile (== "") . drop (length first) $ ls
             -- ^ (2) drop all empty lines
```

In order to split a string into its lines, you can simply use `lines`. To get the number of words in a `Paragraph`, you simply sum over the number of words in each line

```
singleParagraphCount :: Paragraph -> Int
singleParagraphCount = sum . map lineWordCount
```

The words in each line are simply `length . words`:

```
lineWordCount :: Line -> Int
lineWordCount = length . words
```

So all in all we get the following function:

```
wordsPerParagraph :: String -> [Int]
wordsPerParagraph = map (singleParagraphCount) . parify . lines
```

Answer (score 3):

First: you don't want to be bothered with dirty `IO()` any more than necessary, so the signature should be

```
wordsPerParagraph :: String -> [Int]
```

As for doing this: you should first split up the text in paragraphs. Counting the words in each of them is pretty trivial then.

What you basically need is match on empty lines (two adjacent newline characters). So I'd first use the `lines` function, giving you a list of lines. Then you separate these, at each empty line:

```
paragraphs :: String -> [String]
paragraphs = split . lines
 where split [] = []
       split (ln : "" : lns) = ln : split lns
       split (ln : lns) = let (hd, tl) = splitAt 1 $ split lns
                          in (ln ++ hd) : tl
```

Comment: thank you.. but i get the error saying  "*** Expression     : ln ++ hd
*** Term           : ln
*** Type           : [Char]
*** Does not match : [[Char]]"

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't use `-` in a function name, you would have to use `_` instead (or better, use camelCase as leftroundabout suggests below).

Here is a function which satisfies your type signature:

```
paragraph_words = length . words
```

This first splits the text into a list of words, then counts them by returning the length of that list of words.

However this does not completely solve the problem because you haven't written code to split your text into paragraphs.

Comment: Using underscores is extremely uncommon amongst Haskell programmers, it's definitely preferrable to use the CamelCase convention.