# having error when trying to calculating number of words per paragraph in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am new to Haskell and functional programing.

My aim is to calculate the number of paragraphs in a text document and the number of words in each paragraph.

I try to do this by the following steps:

1. I convert the paragraph in to a line

   ```
   type Line      = String
   type Paragraph = [String]

   parify :: [Line] -> [Paragraph]
   parify [] = []
   parify ls 
     | null first = parify rest          
     | otherwise  = first : parify rest
     where first = takeWhile (/= "") ls  
       rest  = dropWhile (== "") . drop (length first) $ ls
   ```
2. Then I count the number of words in each line

   ```
   lineWordCount :: Line -> Int
   lineWordCount = length . words

   singleParagraphCount :: Paragraph -> Int
   singleParagraphCount = sum . map lineWordCount



   wordsPerParagraph :: [String]-> [Int]
   wordsPerParagraph = map (singleParagraphCount) . parify . lines
   ```

I want a result like this:

```
[12, 20, 8]
```

like number of words in each paragraph respectively.

i get the error

```
*** Term           : wordsPerParagraph
*** Type           : [Char] -> [Int]
*** Does not match : [String] -> [Int]
```

Comment: What do you currently get? What don't you like about it?

Comment: Where in your code do you split the document into paragraphs? I'd think you would need to split at `'.'` or something.

Comment: Where's the code for `singleParagraphCount` and `sepearatelines`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `lines :: [Char] -> [String]` which makes `wordsPerParagraph` be `wordsPerParagraph :: [Char] -> [Int]` but your signature is `[String] -> [Int]`

Note, `String` is the same as `[Char]`. So maybe you have a typo in the signature you wrote and you desired `String -> [Int]` instead of `[String] -> [Int]`

Comment: +1, although I don't get why the OP hasn't [simply copied all code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20827502/1139697).