# word count utility in Haskell

Tags: haskell, count, lines, word-count

I'm fairly new to Haskell. I've been trying to create a utility to count the number of words and lines in Haskell for a few days to help me understand the language better. However, I'm struggling to get it working.

So far, I have:

```
wordCountUtility = do

       putStrLn "Please enter the filename:"

       filename <- getLine

       putStrLn ("The file name you have entered is: " ++ filename)

      contents <- readFile filename -- read the file specified in “name” into “contents”

      lower <- (return . map toLower) contents

      putStrLn lower
```

I have tried to use 'chop' and found `print . length . words =<< getContents` and have modified it a number of times, but I have had no luck.
I've also had a look at quite a few similar answers on Stack Overflow, such as : [identifying number of words in a paragraph using haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826497/identifying-number-of-words-in-a-paragraph-using-haskell)

The output should be somewhat similar to this:

```
Amount of Lines within the file
Lines : 10

Amount of Words found within the file
Words : 110
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: so what exactly is your problem?  The code you've posted isn't formatted correctly on SO, I would first recommend fixing that, but you've pretty much just described what you'd like to do, not what problems you're having.

Comment: Sorry im new to stack overflow and it didn't copy the code correctly over. I was having problems with the count function as i wanted to return the number of lines and number of words in a file. I have now been able to fix this.

Comment: The new issue i am having though is that ReadFile isn't returning the correct number of lines. For example if i give it the file "new.txt" which has 4 lines - it returns 4 however when i feed it in through the console it returns one :( any help? thanks

Comment: UPDATE - managed to fix that too. was an alignment issue. Thanks anyway!

Comment: you haven't posted any code that actually counts lines or words. Are you sure you have the relevant code in your question? Also, you can edit you post to update it with more information or fix formatting, and I would encourage you to put any relevant information in the post itself and not in the comments. Comments are meant more for clarification and should be considered transient, all relevant information should appear in the question so that others can find it more easily.

Comment: **Please don't do invalid edits for your question. I have done a rollback.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `wordCountUtility` should probably be not be counting words yet. You should just stop at something like

```
commandLineUtility :: (String -> String) -> IO ()
commandLineUtility fn = do
       putStrLn "Please enter the filename:"
       filename <- getLine
       putStrLn ("The file name you have entered is: " ++ filename)
       contents <- readFile filename -- read the file specified in “name” into “contents”
       lower <- (return . fn) contents
       putStrLn lower
```

(I am keeping this as close to your text as possible.)  Now, though, you have to figure out what 
`(String -> String)` function you want to apply. This is a pure function and should be developed separately. So you might write:

```
cwlcount :: String -> (Int, Int, Int)
cwlcount str = (length str, length (words str), length (lines str))

format :: (Int, Int, Int) -> String
format (c,w,l) = unlines $
     ["Number of characters:"
     , show c
     , "Number of words:"
     , show w
     , "Number of lines:"
     , show l
     ]
```

So `(format . cwlcount) :: String -> String` and you can write:

```
 main :: IO ()
 main = commandLineUtility (format . cwlcount)
```

Of course there are a million objections to this program, but you can improve it by investigating the parts piecemeal. For one thing, it is irritating that the whole list of characters is brought into memory and three length calculations are made for it separately. The `Predude.getLine` is not very user friendly either...

At the moment, then, our results look so:

```
$ ghci Sonia_CS.hs 
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Sonia_CS.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
>>> main
Please enter the filename:
Sonia_CS.hs
The file name you have entered is: Sonia_CS.hs
Number of characters:
816
Number of words:
110
Number of lines:
25
```

Or better:

```
$ ghc -O2 Sonia_CS.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Sonia_CS.hs, Sonia_CS.o )
Linking Sonia_CS ...
$ ./Sonia_CS 
Please enter the filename:
/usr/share/dict/words
The file name you have entered is: /usr/share/dict/words
Number of characters:
2493109
Number of words:
235886
Number of lines:
235886
```

Comment: Thank you very much Arthur. I managed to come up with a solution which now uses countLines and countWords using this format str = (show (length (lines str))) and this seems to work fine too.

Comment: Right, I was separating the formatting of the results from the gathering of them, as I was separating the IO from the pure calculation. Of course they can all be put together.

Comment: Yes, i do prefer you're method as it looks much cleaner and concise! thank you!!